# Finding probability mass function of two random variables

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a r.v with range $R_X = \{1,2,3,4,5 \}$ and $Y$ another r.v
> with range $R_Y = \{1,2,3,...,X \}$. Find $p_{XY}(x,y)$ and
> $p_{X|Y}(x|y)$.

#### Attempt

We can try to do one by one. For example,

$$ p_{XY}(1,1) = P(X=1 \; \text{and} \; Y=1 ) = P(X=1)+P(Y=1) - P(X=1 \cup Y=1)= \frac{1}{5} + 1 - P(X=1 \cup Y=1) = \frac{1}{5}+1 -\frac{1}{6} = \frac{13}{15}$$

Now, in my notes it says that we should get

$$ p_{XY}(x,y) = \frac{1}{5} \frac{1}{x} $$

for each $x \in R_X$. But, I am unable to understand how we can do this if X and $Y$ are not told to be indepedent.

Comment: Merely knowing the range does not tell us about the distribution.  Have you forgotten to mention that they were Uniformly Distributed?

Comment: the problem is stated as i have written it

Comment: Then it is a poorly stated problem.  Buy a better textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unable to understand how we can do this if $X$ and $Y$ are not told to be indepedent.

You are actually told that they are **dependent** since the range of $Y$ is constrained by the value of $X$.

Thus *if* the variables are meant to be Uniformly Distributed over the given ranges, *then* you have actually been told the *conditional distribution* for $Y$ given $X$ .

$$\mathsf P(Y{=}y\mid X{=}x) ~=~ \frac 1x~\mathbf 1_{x\in \{1,..,5\},y\in\{1,.., x\}}$$